# use ng-src img tag in action of mvc controller

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

in html code, I write this code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
...
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div>Select an image file: <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="fileInput" /></div>
    <div class="cropArea col-md-4">
        <img-crop  image="myImage" result-image="myCroppedImage"></img-crop>
    </div>
    <div>Cropped Image:</div>
    <div><img id="files" class="img-responsive img-circle" ng-src="{{myCroppedImage}}" /></div>
</div>
...
}
```

and i write this code in mvc action to get image with id="files":

```
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModelANDApplicationUser model,
        HttpPostedFileBase files)
    {
        var f = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(files.InputStream);
        ...
    }
```

when I run it, files and f is null. I use [ng-img-crop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-img-crop-full-extended)

Comment: Your file input is named `fileInput`, not `files` (and `<img>` tag does not submit anything when the form is posted - only successful form controls post their name/value pairs)

Comment: `files` is null since there is no file requested - you may use `Request.Files` to grab requested file from file input. Also, HTML helper is preferred over `img` tag to bind image path into model (and include it on POST request).